# IE positioning problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, positioning

In every browser but IE, on [euroworker.no/order](http://euroworker.no/order) the little green arrow under the word "produkt" sits on top of my div container. Why in the world does this not work in IE? Thing is, it works on two pages out of four in IE but all four in other browsers. All the pages are built the same, but for IE it displays this thing like 20px above the roundbigbox.

Any ideas guys?

Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

CSS for the top prgress indicator:

```
#checkoutProgress
{
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 1em;
    height: 30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size:18px;
    float:left;
/*  margin-bottom:22px;*/
    margin-left:0px;

}

#checkoutProgress a
{
    padding: 10px;
    /*border-width: 2px;
    margin-right: 20px;*/
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 17.26px;
    color:#dadada;
    text-transform:uppercase;

}

#checkoutProgress a:hover
{
    padding: 10px;
    /*border-width: 2px;
    margin-right: 20px;*/
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 17.26px;
    color:#818072;

}

/* completed steps */
#checkoutProgress a.completed
{
    border-color: #70D66D;

}

/* current step */
#checkoutProgress a.active
{
 /*   border-color: #ADD8E6;*/
    font-weight: bold;
/*background-color: #fffccc;
border-color: #ADD8E6;*/
background-image:url(../../upload/urhere_arr.png);
background-position:bottom center;
/*padding-left:15px;*/
color:#a3a398;
}
```

For the box:

```
div #roundbigbox {
    background-image:url(../../upload/EW_p_og_L.png);
    background-position:top center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding:5px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    width:760px;
    height:1%;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#dddddd;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    }
```

fieldset css:

```
fieldset.container
{
    border: 0;
}
```

And some HTML:

```
<fieldset class="container">

    <div id="checkoutProgress" class="progressCart">

                <a href="/order" class=" active" id="progressCart"><span>Produkt</span></a>
                <a href="/checkout/selectAddress" class="completed " id="progressAddress"><span>kunde info</span></a>


                <a href="/checkout/shipping" class="completed " id="progressShipping"><span>Leveringsmåte</span></a>

                <a href="/checkout/pay" class="" id="progressPayment"><span>Betaling & Fullfør</span><</a>
            </div>

    </fieldset>         </div>



                <form action="/order... >

    <input type="hidden"...>
    <div id="roundbigbox">
    <p id="pro">Produkter</p>
    More content

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML fragment appears badly formed, there are a couple of ending and closing tags that dont have a match!

First thing to do is validate your XHTML (very important in strict doctype) with the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/). Another thing to look out for with IE is random whitespace - don't ask me why, but try making sure there isn't any extraneous whitespace. These kind of "random" behaviours in IE usually have a source in these problems, I think.

Comment: Just looked at your site too - you have a number of z-indexing issues as well. Definitely time to hit the validator! :)

Comment: Grand idea! I'll do just that.

Comment: Well seems my mac just crashed, so no editing to be done now, thanks anyway.